# Which is the best way to level up a Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

At the moment I am using this strategy:

- Pokemon as the first in party (engaging in all fights, even when I need to switch for a more powerful/better suited Pokemon).
- Exp.Share equipped.
- Fighting the Elite Four + Champion (30 Pokemon with range of 7x)

This strategy works great when I am leveling a low level Pokemon. I tested with Sawk level 18, and he finished at level 82 after one pass (all 5 trainers).

But with Ho-Oh 82 I only got to level 87 (I was expecting 89 or 90). I know that the amount of experience is different, but am I doing it right?

- Should I go full fights with a high level Pokemon (even with
  disadvantage elements)?
- Should I use Lucky Egg instead of Exp.Share?
- Should I use some other method?

How can I improve my technique?

Comment: It depends on your goals. - it sounds like you want the fastest method and don't care about EVs?

Comment: Yes. you are right @Pubby I want hit level 100 as fast as possible. 90% of my Pokemons does not need evolution anymore. But they are below 50 (majority)

Comment: @MichelAyres, EV does not stand for evolution, but 'Effort Value'. Quoting from [Serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/games/evs.shtml), `They determine what stats your Pokémon gets upon levelling up and are gained from battling any Pokémon you come across that award Experience points.`

Comment: @Gwen Thanks for the correction. And NO, I don't care at moment with EV's (Just few Pokemons I care about it, not everyone)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your strategy is good for lower level Pokemon. In Black/White, a lower level Pokemon will gain more EXP than a higher level one when fighting the same Pokemon.

For higher levels you would be better off letting the Pokemon KO opponents by itself, holding a Lucky Egg. If you are level 82 you shouldn't have too much of a problem tackling the whole E4. Try and get a range of move types for coverage and you can probably OHKO most Pokemon.

There is also the [Big stadium and Small Court](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Big_Stadium_and_Small_Court) in Nimbasa City which have high level Pokemon you can fight daily, Cynthia appears in Undella Town in Spring with level 75 Pokemon, and with [Morimoto](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Game_Freak#In_the_games) in the Game Freak building in Castelia City with level 75s as well.

Answer (score 0):

While it is better to train Pokemon manually (I generally go through the routes, working my way up), or putting them in the start of the party and switching them out, you can also get ahold of an action replay. This will allow you you to get unlimited Rare Candy (well, in sets of 99).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use exp. share when they are at lvl 1 to lvl 50, and use a lucky egg for higher lvl. Use rare candy when lvl 80 to 99. Of course, you can use lucky egg at low lvl and lvl up faster.

Answer (score -1):

I have been going to the Big Stadium and Small Court to level my Pokemon daily also, it actually helps so well with leveling, a few days  ago i had a level 20 dewott and it leveled up to around 45 in a few days. it gained 25 levels in a matter of 4 days. if you use this strat you get EVs and levels very quickly.

Comment: 25 levels in four days...isn't really all that fast.  If anything, it's glacial.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say a Rare Candy, which is why they are rare.

Comment: Although it is a valid answer, can you develop on why Rare Candies are a good (best) way to level up a Pokemon. There are some disadvantages in using them (such as not gaining EV points).